# Merge two 'range' tables in microsoft access

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables recording parameters over a depth range with different intervals.  Each table has DEPTH_FROM and DEPTH_TO fields as well as a Primary ID. I need to assign PARAMETER to the PARAMETER A ranges.

Can I do this using a subquery? If I need to split records to then I am willing to (I just don't know how). Alternatively, I'd just like to know which 'bin' the RANGE_B.DEPTH_FROM record falls into.

```
LOCATION
POINTID   X   Y   Z
A123  987654  456788  345

RANGE_A
POINTID   Depth_from  Depth_to  Property_A  PROPERTY_B
A123   0  10  AAA  ???
A123  10  17  BBB  ???
A123  17  30  CCC  ???

RANGE_B      
POINTID   Depth_from  Depth_to  Property_B
A123   0   7  ZZZ        
A123   7  15  CCC
A123  15  30  VVV
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy enough to get a bin:

```
SELECT 
   RANGE_B.Depth_from, 
   RANGE_B.Depth_to, 
   RANGE_A.Depth_from, 
   RANGE_A.Depth_to, 
   RANGE_A.Property_A
FROM RANGE_A, RANGE_B
WHERE RANGE_B.Depth_from Between [RANGE_A].[Depth_from] 
      And [RANGE_A].[Depth_to]
```

If you would like to explain a little more, an answer closer to what you need may be possible.

Comment: The end goal is a series of frequency analyses of PropertyB, grouped by PropertyA. When the data was recorded, it was recorded using variable range lengths.  Essentially I'm trying to reconcile the differing and overlapping ranges